# I have very similar charts in my c# form app (10-20). How can I program this charts with one method where I can pass the chart name as variable?

Tags: c#, methods, charts

I have very similar charts in my c# form app (10-20) (Chart1,Chart2,Chart3.....). The only difference of the charts are the data series. Normally I have to repeat the same code 10–20 times in my project.

How can I program the charts with one method, that I can call multiple times, when I can pass the chart name as a variable. I have searched a lot but found really no solution for that.

My code for one chart is as following:

```
public void Draw_Chart()
{
    chart1.Series.Clear();
    chart1.Titles.Clear();
    chart1.Legends.Clear();
    var newSeries_1 = new Series();
    var newSeries_2 = new Series();
    newSeries_1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
    newSeries_2.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
    chart1.Series.Add(newSeries_1);
    chart1.Series.Add(newSeries_2);
    List_X_Axis.Clear();

    for (int w = 0 ; w <= 940; w++)
    {
        parameter_value_chartX[w] = w;
        //parameter_value_chartY1[w] = 150;
        //parameter_value_chartY1[w] = 250;
    }
        
    newSeries_1.Points.DataBindXY(parameter_value_chartX, parameter_value_chartY1);
    newSeries_2.Points.DataBindXY(parameter_value_chartX, parameter_value_chartY2);

    chart1.BackColor = Color.Gray;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = ".";
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Title = "mm";
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.TitleForeColor = Color.Cyan;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.ForeColor = Color.Cyan;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0d;
    chart1.Series[0].Color = Color.Cyan;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = cur_scale_min;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = cur_scale_max;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.Enabled = AxisEnabled.True;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.Minimum = pos_scale_min;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.Maximum = pos_scale_max;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.Title = "% of Max. Current";
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.TitleForeColor = Color.Yellow;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.LabelStyle.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.Silver;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.MajorTickMark.LineColor = Color.Silver;
    chart1.Series[1].YAxisType = AxisType.Secondary;
    chart1.Series[1].Color = Color.Yellow;
}
```

Comment: The parameter of the method you want should not be the chartname but the chartcontrol itself. So put the code you show in a method give it a Chart Control parameter. replace all mentions of chart1 in that method with the name of the Chart parameter and then call that method with the actual chart control this method should work on. `MyLovelyMethod(chart1);`.

Comment: @Ralf  That was the solution Ralf! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
public void Draw_Chart(Chart chart, Series[] series)
{
    ...
    chart.Series.Clear();
    series.ForEach(s=>chart.Series.Add(s));
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution acc. to Ralf's comment in the following way:

```
...    
Draw_Chart(chart1);
...    
Draw_Chart(chart2);
...    
Draw_Chart(chart3);
...


public void Draw_Chart(Chart chart)
{
chart.Series.Clear();
chart.Titles.Clear();
chart.Legends.Clear();
var newSeries_1 = new Series();
var newSeries_2 = new Series();
newSeries_1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
newSeries_2.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
chart.Series.Add(newSeries_1);
chart.Series.Add(newSeries_2);

...
}
```